# Can I bind a function's local variables to the calling environment?

Tags: r

While trying to debug an R function I came up with the following:
**Is there a way to optionally bind the local variables of a called function to the calling environment?**

For example

```
testFunction <- function(x=1,y=2){
  localVar1 <- x + 2
  localVar2 <- x + y
  sum(x,y)
}

sumXY <- testFunction()
if(exists("localVar1") && exists("localVar2")){
    print("test passed")
}
```

Please note, this functionality would only be used for interactive debugging, and the `<<-` operator is not appropriate for my scripts. 
edit 1: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't alter the function, since I'm using this to test/debug analysis code.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I knew there was a better way to check if a variable 'exists'...lol

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hadley, I'm looking for a quick way to inspect/debug nested functions and their calls. If I could bind the the functions variables to the calling environment, I can 1) inspect them to ensure accuracy and 2) call subsequent analysis nested in the original function.

Comment: I should also mention I'm interested in how R's environment/binding system works, so this question has a didactic value for me. Do you think there is a better way to inspect/debug nested function calls in the REPL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `trace()` to establish a call that saves the evaluation frame of the call to `testFunction()` just before exiting from it.

You can then inspect the contents of the evaluation frame (here assigned to the object `TraceEnv`) as they looked just before that environment was exited.

```
testFunction <- function(x=1,y=2){
  localVar1 <- x + 2
  localVar2 <- x + y
  sum(x,y)
}

trace(testFunction, 
      quote({on.exit(assign("TraceEnv", parent.frame(4), .GlobalEnv))}))

sumXY <- testFunction()

if(with(TraceEnv, exists("localVar1") && exists("localVar2"))){
    print("test passed")
}
# [1] "test passed"
```